# How to annotate a default value inside a android room entity?

Tags: android, android-room

I couldn't find any information how to annotate a SQL - "DEFAULT" value while looking into the [@ColumnInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ColumnInfo.html) docs for the new Android Persistence Library.

Does Room even provide an annotation for default values?

My current solution would be to manually create the corresponding Table ...

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  ...
  MyDefaultValuedCol  TEXT DEFAULT 'Default Value',
  MyDefaultFlagCol    INT  DEFAULT 1
)
```

... and put Room on top.

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyTable")
class MyClass {
    ...

    public String MyDefaultValuedCol;

    public boolean MyDefaultFlagCol;

}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With the release of room persistence 2.2.0, there's a new property added to @ColumnInfo annotation which can be used to specify the default value of a column. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo.html#defaultValue()).

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name", defaultValue = "temp") val name: String
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_modified", defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ) val lastModified: String
)
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning this. but can we set boolean (true/false) as default value. I tried it, but i am getting error.
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_deleted", defaultValue = false) var is_deleted:Boolean,
The boolean literal is not conform to the expected type String

Comment: @Qadir, while I haven't tried it, I believe Room stores booleans as ints.  Assuming that's the case, per https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo.html#defaultValue(), you should be able to do defaultValue = "0" for false.

Comment: Note that the default value you specify here will NOT be used if you simply insert the Entity with /@Insert. In that case, any value assigned in Java/Kotlin will be used. Use /@Query with an INSERT statement and skip this column there in order to use this default value.

Comment: @QadirHussain Room actually stores booleans as "0" (false) or "1" (true). You need to set your default value to one of these for a boolean column.

Answer (score 10):

Room hasn't any annotation for default value, but you can set default value in your entity like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyTable")
class MyClass {
    ...

    public String MyDefaultValuedCol = "defaultString";

    public boolean MyDefaultFlagCol = true;

}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this will not modify the generated SQLite table creation to put the default value.

Comment: That doesn't help when you are executing a statement directly, such as when updating only some fields. We need to be able to generate the defaults in the SQL.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the default value  using `@ColumnInfo` annotation-

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "No name")
public String name;
```

and

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
public int flag;
```

or for any kind of data types
check the reference from here [Google developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo)

Comment: @Ahsan Saeed's answer was good, but I think this was a bit better as it shows that you still need to use string for number fields. This also works for floats, you don't need to add the L after the number it seems

Answer (score 3):

You can check inside your getter method of Entity and set some default value there.

```
@Entity(tableName = "Dashboard")
public class Dashboard {
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "claimNumber")
private String claimNumber;
private String percentage = "0";
private String imagePath = "";

@NonNull
public String getClaimNumber() {
    return claimNumber;
}

public void setClaimNumber(@NonNull String claimNumber) {
    this.claimNumber = claimNumber;
}



public String getPercentage() {
    if (percentage == null || percentage.isEmpty()) {
        return "0";
    }
    return percentage;
}

public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public Dashboard(@NonNull String claimNumber,  String percentage, String imagePath) {
    this.claimNumber = claimNumber;

    this.percentage = percentage;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
```

}

Comment: and what is the point in representing numeric values as data-type `String`?

Comment: There is no point to representing numeric value as String. I just give you an example. @MartinZeitler

Answer (score 0):

For any one facing the situation when you have two foreign keys and "onDelete = CASCADE" you can set the foreign key to a data type that can be set to null
for example:

```
int parent1Id = 0;
int parent2Id = 0;  
//should be:
Long parent1Id = null;
Long parent2Id = null;
```

that way the DB knows that a particular Object/row has no other parent of different type when attempting to delete it when its parent is deleted.

Comment: Why not `Integer` then?

Comment: Because insertion will return a long id, its better to use Long