# "Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL" with Requery after automatic DB migration

Tags: android

I updated my `AbstractFooEntity` class by adding an integer field like below, and I bumped the DB version (the DB is initialized with `new DatabaseSource(context, Models.DEFAULT, DB_VERSION)`.

```java
@Entity
abstract class AbstractFooEntity {
  // this was in DB schema v1
  String someField;

  // added in DB schema v2
  int newField = 0;
}
```

When I deploy this code and the (automatic) DB migration is performed when the user runs the new version of the Android app, I get the following error at runtime: `"Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL"`.

What's the proper way to annotate the entity so that the framework correctly handles the automatic DB migration in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options, first one is probably to be preferred - in the second one, you need to handle possible nullpointers in the code:

**option 1**

```java
@Entity
abstract class AbstractFooEntity {
  ...
  @Column(value = "0")
  int newField;
}
```

**option 2**

```java
@Entity
abstract class AbstractFooEntity {
  ...
  Integer newField;
}
```

Comment: How did you come across the annotation `@Column` for option 1 ? This is the current solution to set default value for a table column : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47918257/4974461

Comment: The `int newField = SOME_VALUE;` didn't work for me in case of migration. Maybe it works only for newly created tables? I checked the generated code, and it didn't see `SOME_VALUE` anywhere. I came to `@Column` solution just by exploring the sample code and docs.

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution of this.

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN colum_name INTEGER DEFAULT 1 not null");
```

add the command : "DEFAUT value" after data type will solve your problem.

Comment: Setting `DEFAULT 1` solved the issue allowing the attribute to be set to `NOT NULL`.

Comment: [Here is the initial issue this solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261997/room-migration-using-existing-boolean-column-types/55304942#55304942), adding a Boolean column to an Android Room database.