# DEFAULT values in Room database (Kotlin)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to migrate from existing Loaders/Content Providers to Room.
I need some columns to have default values. Adding defaults in Kotlin, like `var columnName: Int = 0` but when I check `RoomDatabase_Impl` it ignores the Kotlin Defaults in schema creation. How to introduce DEFAULT values for columns with Room?

Comment: I initialize them during declaration on my pojo(Entity) and that has worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate a default value inside a android room entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905627/how-to-annotate-a-default-value-inside-a-android-room-entity)

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think Room does not provide a way to generate db schema with "ColumnName DEFAULT 1" SQL which would be on db level. I think it assumes that db is accessed only through Entities and if you want to use Entities and raw queries using loaders then you would have to add the default values in all loaders.

Answer (score 0):

use @ColumnInfo annotation

```
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "value")
```