# How to set a fixed value for a item in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a data class which is populated by retrofit. The server (API) has no `id` field in it. So I created a `val id` and assigned it some value say `69`. But once I receive the data, the value of id is not `69`, but `0`. Help please.

```
@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeather(

    @SerializedName("last_updated_epoch")
    val lastUpdatedEpoch: Int,

// ... //

    @SerializedName("gust_kph")
    val gustKph: Float
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 69
}
```

I even tried doing this:

```
data class CurrentWeather(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Int = 69,
// ... //
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905627/how-to-annotate-a-default-value-inside-a-android-room-entity

Comment: Yes I've read that, and that doesn't seem to work. And that is in java too. Can you help me for kotlin?

Comment: @AmitParameshwar : Probably `CurrentWeather` object contains `id` with `0`.

Comment: I thought the same, but that is not the case

Comment: why you need `{` ?

Comment: Even if I remove that block, the value `id` is not assigned

Comment: How you call the id?

Comment: I called it by `weatherAPI.current.id`

Comment: The id is pointed to id in CurrentWeather ?

Comment: Yes it is. There is no other field named `id`. And I have tried naming it different, and it doesn't work

Comment: Try use `Long` instead

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried with `String` and it returned `null`

Comment: remove (autoGenerate = false)

Comment: Still not working

Comment: How can I use this with constructor block? Is it possible to init the values after a network call?

Comment: why not just do like this ? `weatherAPI.current.id = 69`

Comment: I have to store it in a db, and its table should have only 1 entry. All the fields are unique, so I had to create this id field. But its value is not what I assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be a problem with GSON, something with serialization and deserialization as it does not support kotlin properly. Read [Gson Deserialization with Kotlin, Initializer block not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962284/gson-deserialization-with-kotlin-initializer-block-not-called) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeather(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Int = 69,

    @SerializedName("last_updated_epoch")
    val lastUpdatedEpoch: Int,

    // ... //

)
```

**upd.**

This is the object to ready to write to the database.
For your case, you should write a mapper / converter from the Retrofit response object to the Data Entity data class.

Comment: No it is not working, I am populating the data class with retrofit. and there is no `id` field in the response, I am adding that myself. Is that the cause of the problem?