# How to use ForeignKey.SET_DEFAULT in room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm making a note app and every note has a label. There are two tables, One for Notes and one for Labels. Currently, I'm using `ForeignKey.CASCADE` and if the user deletes a Label, notes with that label will be deleted. I want to have a default value so when a label is deleted, the notes get that as the new label and don't get removed.

I think the solution is to use `onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_DEFAULT` but I don't know how and where to use it.

Note Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_notes",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Label.class,
                parentColumns = "label_id",
                childColumns = "note_label_id",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "archived")
    private boolean isArchive;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_text")
    private String noteText;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_date")
    private String noteDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_label_id")
    private int noteLabel;
```

Label Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_label")
public class Label {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "label_id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "label_name")
    private String labelName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check docs from [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey#set_default).
They said:

> The "SET DEFAULT" actions are similar to SET_NULL, except that each of the child key columns is set to contain the columns default value instead of NULL.

So you have to put the default value. like this

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "c_id", defaultValue = "1")
 private long id;
```

Comment: Can you show me codes for the `defaultValue` method?

Comment: just be sure you have the lastest version of Room '2.2.0'

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was on '1.1.1' (Pre AndroidX). I migrated to AndroidX and now I can use it

Answer (score 1):

I just read the inline documentation for here is what it said about

> The "SET DEFAULT" actions are similar to SET_NULL, except that each of
>   the child key columns is set to contain the columns default value
>   instead of NULL.

Which means you just need to define it. It will set the default value of your column in the Notes table. While designing your schema for Note table you have to make sure to link it with default value for the column you map.

Comment: So How should I define it? It would be great if you show some sample codes

Comment: @Hamed Here is way for adding the default value for column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905627/how-to-annotate-a-default-value-inside-a-android-room-entity

Answer (score 1):

To set a foreign key's **onDelete** or **onUpdate** action you would use a combination of **SET_DEFAULT** in the Foreign key annotation along with setting the default value to be used in the respective column's **@ColumnInfo** to specify the value that the column defaults to.

e.g.

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_notes",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Label.class,
                parentColumns = "label_id",
                childColumns = "note_label_id",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_DEFAULT)) //<<<<<<<<<
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "archived")
    private boolean isArchive;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_text")
    private String noteText;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_date")
    private String noteDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_label_id", defaultValue = "1") //<<<<<<<<<<
    private int noteLabel;
```

**Caution**

The value used, must obviously be a value that will not result in a conflict, so at the minimum the default value must be a value that exists in the reference column of the parent table.

e.g.

If in the above `DELETE FROM tbl_label WHERE label_id = 1` were run, then the above would result in a Foreign Key conflict.

For example consider this example based upon the above Entities and suitable Dao's (with SET_DEFAULT):-

```
    mNoteDao = mDatabase.noteDao();
    mNoteDao.insertLabels(
            new Label("Label1"),
            new Label("Label2"),
            new Label("Label3")
    );
    mNoteDao.insertNotes(
            new Note(false,"Note1 uses lable 3","2019-01-01",3),
            new Note(false,"Note2 uses label 2","2019-01-01",2),
            new Note(false,"Note3 uses label 1","2019-01-01",1)
    );
    logAllNoteInfo("After populate\n\t");
    mNoteDao.deleteLabelById(3);
    logAllNoteInfo("After delete label 3\n\t");
    mNoteDao.deleteLabelById(1);
    logAllNoteInfo("After delete label 1\n\t");
```

This adds 3 labels and 3 notes each using one of the labels. The label with an id of 3 is deleted, then the label (the default label) is deleted.

The resultant output starts with :-

```
2019-10-16 08:02:49.795 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After populate
        Note ID is 1 Text is Note1 uses lable 3 Label is Label3
2019-10-16 08:02:49.795 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After populate
        Note ID is 2 Text is Note2 uses label 2 Label is Label2
2019-10-16 08:02:49.796 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After populate
        Note ID is 3 Text is Note3 uses label 1 Label is Label1
2019-10-16 08:02:49.804 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After delete label 3Note ID is 1 Text is Note1 uses lable 3 Label is Label1
2019-10-16 08:02:49.805 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After delete label 3Note ID is 2 Text is Note2 uses label 2 Label is Label2
2019-10-16 08:02:49.806 5914-5914/? D/NOTEANDLABEL: After delete label 3Note ID is 3 Text is Note3 uses label 1 Label is Label1
```

The tables are populated as expected and after the deletion of Label3 Note 1 now references Label1 instead of Label3 as per the SET_DEFAULT action.

BUT the attempt to delete Lable1 results in an exception as per :-

```
2019-10-16 08:02:49.808 5914-5914/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2019-10-16 08:02:49.809 5914-5914/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: arm.androidroommigrations, PID: 5914
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{arm.androidroommigrations/arm.androidroommigrations.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:831)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:756)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:66)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:46)
        at arm.androidroommigrations.NoteDao_Impl.deleteLabelById(NoteDao_Impl.java:181)
        at arm.androidroommigrations.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
```