# Roomdb does know how to return field when it has default value?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-database

This work very well

```
@Entity
data class OrderVoucher(
        @PrimaryKey var id: Int? = null,
        var orderId: Int? = null,
       var printCount: Int? = null
}
```

but when I add defult values

```
   var printCount: Int=0
```

roomdb says does not know about printCount
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [printCount]

Comment: hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905627/how-to-annotate-a-default-value-inside-a-android-room-entity) helps

Comment: Please provide the complete error log.

Comment: Did you update the Database version after making the change?

Answer (score 0):

Every property in your data class has to have @ColumnInfo annotation, check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) for more information