# How to create instance of a data class for android Room which has fields with default values?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")
data class Data(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "blob") val blob: ByteArray,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp", defaultValue = "(strftime('%s','now'))")
                val timetamp: String)
```

How to create an instance of this class?
I want to create it like this:

`Data(blob = byteArrayOf(1,2,3))`

I have found a way for this example using default parameter values(updated declaration below), but for ordinary fields, I don't know how to specify a not nullable value which will be considered as no value: I have tried `ColumnInfo.VALUE_UNSPECIFED`,`"NULL"`,`""`  but no luck with it.

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")
data class Data(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "blob") val blob: ByteArray,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
                val timetamp: String = System.currentTimeMillis.toString())
```

Comment: It might be helpfull for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905627/how-to-annotate-a-default-value-inside-a-android-room-entity

Comment: I have seen it and used to create declaration, but my question is how to create object without specifying value and using default value from annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, put all the **has-default-value** parameters **AT THE END**, like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")
data class Data(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "blob") 
    val blob: ByteArray,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    val id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    val timetamp = System.currentTimeMillis()   //use Long type for time, recommended
)
```

Then you can just `Data(byteArrayOf(1,2,3))`.